# Java: one of many keys map

Tags: java, java-8

I got a Map, which may contain one of the following Keys

```
Map<String, String> map = getMap();
```

I now want to check if one of some Keys are set. My current approach is to chain multiple `map.getOrDefault(...)`

```
Address address = new Address();
address.setStreet(map.getOrDefault("STORE_STREET"
    , map.getOrDefault("OFFICE_STREET", ...));
```

or check for each key if it exists in the map.

```
if(map.containsKey("STORE_STREET")){
   address.setStreet(map.get("STORE_STREET"));
}else if(map.containsKey("OFFICE_STREET")){
   address.setStreet(map.get("OFFICE_STREET"));
}
```

Is there any way to make this easier/better to read? Unfortunately the map is given as such.

Comment: So, you want to go through different keys in a map and find and use the first that is set?

Comment: `address.setStreet(map.getOrDefault("STORE_STREET"
    , map.getOrDefault("OFFICE_STREET", ...));` looks optimal to me.

Comment: How about having a collection of strings like "store_street" etc, and looping through them while checking for containsKey and then setting them in the address object?

Comment: @Adowrath yes, exactly

Comment: @Exception_al 
 seems more complex to me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Normally, `getOrDefault` would be the way to go, but if you have multiple alternative keys, this does not only affect readability, but also turn the performance advantage into the opposite. With code like:

```
address.setStreet(map.getOrDefault("STORE_STREET", map.getOrDefault("OFFICE_STREET", ...));
```

You are looking up the alternative keys first, to get the fall-back value, before even looking whether the primary key (or a key with a higher precedence) is present.

One solution would be

```
Stream.of("STORE_STREET", "OFFICE_STREET", ...)
      .map(map::get)
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .findFirst()
      .ifPresent(address::setStreet);
```

When executing this a single time, its performance might be less than a simple loop, due to the higher initialization overhead, however, the performance difference would be irrelevant then. For frequent execution, there will be no significant difference, so you should decide based on the readability (which is subjective, of course).

Answer (score 1):

```
String []keys = {"STORE_STREET", "OFFICE_STREET", ...};
for (String k : keys)
{
   if (map.containsKey(k))
     return map.get(k);
}

return ""; // or throw an exception
```